# Use lookup from one Azure DF Pipeline into another Pipeline

Tags: azure, lookup, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a Lookup Activity in a pipeline. Sequential to it i have multiple Execute Pipeline Activities. I want to use that lookup within the execute pipeline activities. Is that possible? Or re-creating the lookup in each the execute pipeline activity is the only option?

I'm using ADF v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the output of lookup activity to an execute pipeline, you need to define a parameter in execute pipeline, and use '@activity('LookupTableList').output.value' to set the value of the pipeline parameter, reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal#create-pipelines to see how **TriggerCopy** execute pipeline use the output of **LookupTableList** lookup activity, which is the exactly same as your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand your scenario. If you just need the result of lookup, why don’t just pass the output of lookup to your execute pipeline activities? Why need are-create a lookup activity?

Comment: that's exacly what i want! How do you pass the output of a lookup to an execute pipeline activity?